# How to make my image grid responsive / resize and setting breakpoints

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive

I am trying to make grid which contains images, text overlays and links (also a button for each section if i can work out how to place it where i want it).

My main problem is trying to get it to be responsive. I have cobbled together some CSS but not sure how to get the sections to run underneath each other past the breakpoint.

Any help would be really appreciated. I also think my CSS will need a fair amount of work but at the moment it looks fine visually.

thanks

`CSS`

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.jk-main-categories {
 max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.jk-main-categories > div {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
.jk-main-categories {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1 fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);

}

.jk-weddings {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 7;
  background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner11.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 500px;
 margin:5px;
}


.jk-party-planning {
  grid-column: 4 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner6.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
 margin: 5px;
}

.jk-corporate-events {
  grid-column: 4 / 7;
  grid-row: 4 / 7;
  background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner15.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 min-width: 300px;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 5px;
}

a#jacqueline-kennedy-luxury-weddings > h2 {
  color: white;
 line-height: 1.1em;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(51,51,51, 0.5)
}

a#jacqueline-kennedy-luxury-party-planning > h3 {
  color: white;
 line-height: 1.1em;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(51,51,51, 0.5)
}

a#jacqueline-kennedy-corporate-event-planning > h3 {
  color: white;
 line-height: 1.1em;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(51,51,51, 0.6)
}

div.jk-weddings > p {
 max-width: 400px;
 min-width: 300px;
 line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="jk-main-categories">
  <div class="jk-weddings"><a href="http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/appointments" id="jacqueline-kennedy-luxury-weddings"><h2>Plan<br>Your<br>Perfect<br>Day</h2></a><p>Have the wedding of your dreams professionally planned and managed making sure your special day goes the way you planned.</p></div>
  <div class="jk-party-planning"><a href="http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/appointments" id="jacqueline-kennedy-luxury-party-planning"><h3>Luxury<br>Party<br>Planning</h3></a></div>
  <div class="jk-corporate-events"><a href="http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/appointments" id="jacqueline-kennedy-corporate-event-planning"><h3>Corporate<br>Events</h3></a></div>
</div>
```

I am guessing I need some kind of media CSS but I think i've painted myself into a corner with the way i have done things so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use media queries for more specific options
don´t forget to add this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

You´ll have to split up a few lines of code for at least
a basic "destop style" and a simple "mobile style".

As example for desktops:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
// specific for desktops 
.jk-weddings {
 grid-column: 1 / 4;
 grid-row: 1 / 7;
 background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner11.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 500px;
 margin:5px;
}
}
```

As a really quick and dirty example for mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
.jk-weddings {
 grid-column: 1 / 4;
 grid-row: 1 / 7;
 background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner11.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin:5px;
}
}
```

If you look at this simple example everything i´ve done 
is removing the min-width.

All classes that was given a "min-width" should be 
declared for each device you want to support.

This way is not the best way to use media queries, 
they can be used to build complex, responsiv designs.

Some more information about media queries and how to use them could be 
found right here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help, seemed to have worked it out now thanks to your example :)